# In angular directive don't work function from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

guys! 
I build form from dynamic data. And in future i need to compile this form, put data to form and submit. I build form by this way:

```
<div>
<form name="pageForm">
<div>
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="item in formStructure.form_data"
dynamic="item" templates="templates"></div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

I have templates for forms parts/inputs in js code like this:

```
$scope.templates.checkbox = '<label><input ng-required="item.conf.required"' + 
'ng-model="formData[item.conf.name]" type="checkbox" > {{item.conf.title}} </label>';
```

And use such directive:

```
function dynamic ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: { dynamic: '=dynamic',
            templates: '=templates',
            eventlstn: '&'
        },
        link: function postLink(scope, ele, attrs) {
            scope.$watch( 'dynamic' , function(html){
                scope.item = html;
                ele.html(scope.templates[html.type]);
                $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    };
}
```

After form is buided, when i click on some elements with ng-click="someFunctionINController()" nothing hepens.

Also on my html i can't access to form data with ng-model.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CINtDt?p=preview)

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle or plunkr?

Comment: Here is plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/CINtDt?p=preview

Comment: can you provide in post and plunkr last version of code, now it not same?

Comment: you main problem in plunkr - you use same controller twice: in directive - `controller: 'formReadyController',` and in html - `ng-controller="formReadyController"`

Comment: try see fixed [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/39EWE1HoYc5M8cP0HtIV?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution:
I modified directive:

```
function dynamic ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        scope: false,
        link: function postLink(scope, ele, attrs) {
            scope.$watch( 'dynamic' , function(){
                ele.html(scope.templates[scope.item.type]);
                $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    };
}
```

With `scope: false` directive use the same scope with controller. 
And now it works. Thanks, Grundy for your time.

In future i plan put this solution (Drag'n'Drop form builder with extended functionality) to public, hope it will help someone.